# ClassNotFoundException and UnavailableException on ObjectifyFilter during deployment

Tags: google-app-engine, exception, deployment, objectify

I attempted to deployed my first app-engine w/ Objectify, but I received both the ClassNotFoundException and UnavailableException on ObjectifyFilter.

I have both guava18.0.jar and objectify-5.1.5.jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder and I also added both the my class path.

Does anyone know what else I need to do?

Sample of the error message below:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:79)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:81)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)`
```

Comment: You need to post the full stack trace and your objectify initialization code. Likely candidates - 1) multiple objectify libraries - clean and redeploy, 2) registering objectify entities in the 'wrong' way - see objectify best practices docs or 3) an exception being thrown from a static init block. My guess is it is the second point causing the third.

Answer (score 0):

Strange as it sounds, I created a second instance of the project and everything is working fine.  I compared the class path and the content of the WEB-INF\lib and both instances are identical.

For the second instance, I did use **Add Jar** instead of **Add External Jar** to include the jar files mentioned.

P.S.  I am using Eclipse Luna